# Breaking cyclic dependency in constructor

Tags: java, dependency-injection, dependencies, circular-dependency, decoupling

I'm writing a Java class to manage a hex map (`class GameMapImpl implements GameMap`) that contains `Cell` objects. Cell objects are saved in a `HashMap<Hex,Cell>`, where the key is the position on the hex map.

The whole thing used to be very tightly coupled between cells and GameMap, with a cyclic dependency between the two, but I'm trying to refactor it to allow more easy testing.

(code below is simplified)

```
public interface GameMap {
    void hasCell(Hex hex);
    void getCell(Hex hex);
}

class GameMapImpl implements GameMap
{
    private Map<Hex, Cell> cellMap;

    GameMapImpl(Set<Cell> cells) {
        cellMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (Cell cell : cells) {
            // check some conditions on the cells
            // ensure the map is correct, e.g. only one cell
            // of a particular type

            // ensures that the cellMap key is always the cell's position.
            cellMap.put(cell.position(), cell);
        }
    }

    //obvious implementation for hasCell and getCell methods
}
```

Each `Cell` needs to have a `Hex position` field so it can look up its own position in the `GameMap`. In addition, `Cell` objects need to have a reference to the owning `GameMap`, to perform common useful operations such as looking for their neighbours.

```
public class Cell {
    final Hex position;
    final GameMap gameMap;

    Cell(Hex position, GameMap gameMap) {
        this.position = position;
        this.gameMap = gameMap;
    }

    public Set<Cell> getNeighbours() {
        //perform operation that needs both gameMap and position
    }
}
```

The `GameMap` is built in a `GameMapBuilder`, which provides a `Set<Cell>` to the `GameMap` constructor.

```
public class GameMapBuilder {
    public GameMap build(...) { // args omitted for simplicity

        Set<Cells> cells = new HashSet<>();
        for (... : ...)
        {
            Hex position = calculatePosition(...);
            Cell cell = new Cell(position, gameMap);
        }
        GameMap gameMap = new GameMap(cells);
        return gameMap;
    }
}
```

As you can probably see, the last snippet of code is wrong, because i'm referencing a non-existent `gameMap` variable. Here lies my problem: if I create the `GameMap` after initializing the cells, I cannot pass it in the `Cell`'s constructor. If I do the opposite, I cannot pass the `Set<Cells>` to the `gameMap` in order to initialize correctly.

Does any more experienced programmer have an idea on how to decouple correctly these two classes?

Alternatively, I can go back to the previous tightly coupled design and just assume that Cells exist only when a GameMap creates them. Being these small objects and contained in the same package, it wouldn't be that big of a deal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use setter for passing `GameMap` into `Cell` not constructor. You can make it package-protected to hide it from other code and call setter in `GameMap` constructor or in another loop in `GameMapBuilder`. All known DE-frameworks use setters to solve circular dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you use a builder. Basically what you did in the builder is took code away from the `GameMap` constructor. If you were to put this code in the `GameMap` constructor you can give `this` to the `Cell` constructor.

If you still want to keep the builder code separated from the `GameMap` code you can make a static method on the builder that the `GameMap` constructor calls and pass `this` (the `GameMap` object) as a parameter.

Comment: That's what I had before refactoring, but I'd like to do something to break the circular dependency.